# How to change confidence interval display format?

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I have a dataset like this:

```
Row   B1    B2    B3         G1         G2   G3
 1   6.19   0.69       0.30       0 0   0
 2    100   100    100        94.87 98.73   90.56
 3    100   90.24     100         40    78.94   87.5
 4    93.90 96.15     95.29      98.82  100 100
 5    100   98.38      100       88.88  95.87   83.56
 6    93.90 96.15     95.29      98.82  100 100
```

And so on, for 25000 rows.
For each row, I need to calculate the difference between the B columns and the G columns, and get the  confidence interval.
This is what I have so far:

```
    data=read.table("1.txt", header=T, sep="\t")
    boys=data[,grep('B',names(data))]
    girls=data[,grep('G',names(data))]
    ci= sapply(1:nrow(data),function(i){wilcox.test(as.numeric(boys[i,]),as.numeric(girls[i,]),exact=FALSE,correct=FALSE,conf.int=TRUE,conf.level=0.95)$conf.int})
```

My problem is, every time I do this, I get the confidence intervals to display with the 2 numbers of the interval one above the other. For example, like this: 
5
15
(for row 1, say)

How do I get the CI from each row to display in a single row, like this: 5,15

Would be grateful for any help in this regard!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to compare column `B1` only to `G1`? Or to `G1`, `G2`, and `G3`?

Comment: Looks like you just need the transpose function: `?t`. That's a fairly common need since `sapply` returns values in column-major order rather than what people often expect.

Comment: I want to compare all the B's to the G's (so average of the B's to the average of the G's)

Comment: #DWin: How do I use the transpose function? Should I do so after I populate the variable ci?

Comment: Wrap your `sapply` in `t()`, i.e. `ci = t(sapply(  .what you already have. ))`

Comment: #DWin: Oh, I got it! Thanks so much! I just wrote cit= t(ci) and got the whole thing in rows.

Comment: #shujaa: Thanks, shujaa!